# Codeigniter Cache a single

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I have the following functions :

```
   class Pharmacy extends MY_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index() {

            $data['pack'] = $this->package();
            $data['name'] = $this->getName();
            $data['title'] = $this->title();
            $data['name'] = $this->getName();
            $data['tests'] = $this->get_tests();
            $data['patient_bio'] = $this->patient_bio();
            $data['procedure_name'] = $this->getProcedure();

           //Pass the contents of pharmacy view to the  template view. 
            $data1['contents'] = 'pharmacy';
            $finaldata = array_merge($data, $data1);
            $this->base_params($finaldata);
        }

        function base_params($data) {
          //Load the  base template for the function.
            $this->output->cache(3000);
            $data['title'] = 'Pharmacy';
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }
    }
```

I want to cache the foloowing view template but when I pass the   $this->output->cache(3000); it caches the whole webpage instead of caching only the  template view. How can I cache only the  template view ?

Comment: How about making your data (mysql) cache instead of caching the template?

Comment: I take it the template view is inside `base_params()`? Or do you want to cache the data you've got inside `index()`? Also, what's lead you to want to cache these? Are they using a lot of overhead or taking a long time to load?